# RegEx for machine.name=Blah-01 in Java

Tags: java, regex

Needs some help with using a reg ex to get the machine name from a string.  Note there are also new lines between the name/value pairs.  Here is the string:

> event has happened on id=5656565655, login.user.id=5453453345, machine.name=ubuntu-1, more name value pairs here

The regex that I though was working was:

```
final Matcher m = Pattern.compile("machine.name=(\\.+),")
```

I had a W instead of the DOT before, but that missed machine names with numerics and dashes in them.  Once I went to DOT I get zero matches.  I need to extract the value of the machine name from the string.  Will someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By putting a `\` in front of the dot, you are asking for a literal dot. What you probably want is everything up to the comma, which can be done with

```
final Matcher m = Pattern.compile("machine\\.name=([^,]+),")
```

or with a non-greedy modifier:

```
final Matcher m = Pattern.compile("machine\\.name=(.+?),")
```

Comment: @aioobe - Good catch! It works either way if there's actually a "." between "machine" and "name", but without your edit it would also match "machine&name" or any other single character.

Answer (score 1):

`"machine\\.name=([^,]+),"`

this means all non-coma characters.

As always there are a lot of solutions. It is only one of them.